# Practical sources of entropy on an Android device?

Tags: random-number-generator, entropy

What Android API's can be used a practical sources of entropy ?

Given the requirement of sourcing entropy on the phone for purposes of seeding a PRNG, what are good options ?

Edit:

I have a hard external requirement to periodically supplement the entropy of the RNG, which in the case of SecureRandom, I will do by calling setSeed and passing in the new entropy.

The Android docs for setSeed state:  `The given seed supplements, rather than replaces, the existing seed. Thus, repeated calls are guaranteed never to reduce randomness.`.

As a result, I'm pretty confident that this is the safe and correct way to supplement the entropy of the RNG, but I need guidance as to appropriate on-device sources of entropy.

I have a FIPS compliant HSM on the server side that will contribute, but I need a safe source of additional entropy on the mobile device side.

Recommended options include the lower-order bits of random chunks of memory and phone sensors, and I would appreciate comment in this regard.

Comment: As the hardware in cell phones, particularly android, is definitely lowest bidder, even if you get a good seed, you still have issues:  http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/338.html.  Assuming that the PRNG quality doesn't bother you, can you use an external source for the seed? Such as random.org?

Comment: @bdegnan random.org is not safe since you don't have any guarantee that it's really random and not being logged.

Comment: @Conrado it was an example.  There are other external sources.

Comment: @bdegnan the same applies for any other external source...

Comment: SO Q/A [Where can I get a reliable source of entropy (real randomness byte[])?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51787670/1820553)

Comment: @Conrado physics doesn't give you very good sources locally as they are: slow, and power hungry.  As a hardware person, you generally make things less good for the sake of power.  The idea that an internal source would necessarily be better/worse is mostly a function of management.  The best answer would probably be "if you have an accelerometer, shake vigorously"

Comment: @bdegnan Linux uses a bunch of different sources for seeding its RNG, it doesn't even need special hardware for that (it uses timings of network and disk events), though a lot of [ARM SoCs already provide hardware RNGs](https://www.usenix.org/system/files/conference/woot14/woot14-kaplan.pdf). The point is that all of that is already handled by the kernel, so just use SecureRandom.

Comment: If you want crude unpredictability and you don't trust the internal for some reason, concat and hash as much indeterminate data as you can: timings (epoc, uptime, ptime, etc), memory stats, battery %, gps location, light level, accelerometer snapshot, nearby wifi hotspot ssids, screen brightness, microphone samples, camera samples, and even os random, because it can't hurt in this construction, and it just might be the single best source in the above stack..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use [SecureRandom](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/SecureRandom) and let the OS take care of it.

Comment: Yes. Reading `/dev/urandom` with one's favorite file API will do in native code.Or `/dev/random` is you want "true entropy" for some vague definition of that.

Comment: I don't like comment only answers. Also, the /dev/urandom is under the change in Linux. It would be [no more blocking](https://lwn.net/Articles/808575/).

Comment: @fgrieu Is there anything to the urban myth that `/dev/random` is somehow "better"? I read so many conflicting things about it. Some say `/dev/urandom` is just as good and you're an idiot for using `/dev/random`, others say it's actually better and you should never use `/dev/urandom` as source for randomness in cryptographic processes. I tried looking at [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/41595/when-to-use-dev-random-over-dev-urandom-in-linux) but it could be out of date these days.

Comment: @MechMK1 Unfortunately, neither of those APIs does what most people want. Fortunately, Linux now has [getrandom](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrandom.2.html) which does what most people actually want and eliminates the need to choose between two APIs that almost do what you want but one sometimes doesn't block when you absolutely need it to and one sometimes blocks when you definitely don't want it to.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Luckily, I am not in a position where I have to write any cryptographic code. Because if I were, I would as soon as possible aim not to be in such a position anymore.

Comment: @MechMK1: I have a marvelous answer to your question-as-comment, but the limited space a crypto.SE comment allows won't allow me to expose it here :-). Plus the whole question, however interesting, is more about the history of pitfalls in Unixes implementations, than modern academic crypto. Thus I'm afraid it's kinda off-topic. Therefore I'll only second David Schmartz, and that baring availability of `getrandom`, on a platform I'd really trust I'd use `/dev/urandom`, rather than mix in extra entropy source for peace of mind as I've sometime done in professional practice.